# JMETER - MYSQL Workbench Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown character set index for field '255' received from server.)

Tags: mysql, jmeter, database-connection, workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench 8.0.18 previously I have installed latest version 8.0.19.
[image]
I have added the connectors in \apache-jmeter-5.1.1\lib
[image]

If I enter incorrect password then I get this error -- which is expected and correct - **Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))**

And If I put incorrect db then I get this
[image]

This suggest JMeter is able to connect with MYSQL Workbench but keep getting the error
**Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown character set index for field '255' received from server.)**
[image]

I am able to connect to other MYSQL DB on cpanel DB with pretty much same connection strings.

Please help

[image]

This is what my JMETER JDBC Connection String
[image]

Comment: Have you tried this https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Java-Java-Agent-Installation-JVM/java-sql-SQLException-Unknown-initial-character-set-index-255/td-p/35477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a conflicting jar file of JDBC.jar was in my lib folder not sure why I needed and used for but as soon as I removed it connected successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Execute [SHOW VARIABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-variables.html) command to view `character_set_client` and `character_set_connection` variables values:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
```

[image]

and make sure that your `characterEncoding` is [matching Java encoding](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html)

If you're absolutely sure that your connection string is fine then try do upgrade to the [latest version of the Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

More information: [MySQL Database and JMeter - How to Test Your Connection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-database-and-jmeter-how-to-test-your-connection/)

Comment: I get this character_set_client utf8mb4
character_set_connection utf8mb4
character_set_database utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results utf8mb4
character_set_server utf8mb4
character_set_system utf8
character_sets_dir C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\              I still get an error when I try this **jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sakila?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useConfigs=maxPerformance**        What should I try